# Are JSON APIs supposed to return strings or JavaScript Objects?

Tags: json, node.js, api

Let's say I ask Mailchimp for subscriber data, and they send back an http request with JSON in the body. Should I be able to go:

```
var thingy = body.property;
```

Or should I have to go:

```
var object = JSON.parse(body);
var thingy = object.property;
```

?

Also, does the node.js body parse parse JSON for me?

Comment: you can directly access the json data. Parse is not required.

Comment: Well, with Mailchimp's new API, sometimes it is, which is what prompted the question. Now, they should at least be consistent, but why would it be okay to send raw objects over the wire? Isn't stringing and parsing what keeps the format safe?

Comment: It will always be a string, unless whatever you are using to send the request does the parsing of the response for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is sent over the wire from the server as a string.  That's what JSON is - a string format.

Whether or not it arrives at your code as a string or as already parsed Javascript object depends entirely upon the code you are using to make the http request and perhaps what headers the server sets and what auto-detection the code doing the Ajax call makes.

If the response header sets the type to json, then some code making the request will automatically parse it for you into Javscript.  Other code will leave that to the caller to do.  If the server does not set the proper headers, then some code will auto-detect it as JSON and parse it and other code will not.

So ... bottom line.  It depends entirely upon what the server is doing in its response and what code is being use to make the request.  You can very easily just do a `console.log(body)` and see whether you have a JSON string or an already parsed Javascript object.

If you really weren't sure what behavior you would get, you can test the type and act accordingly (though a given server and calling code should be consistent so you shouldn't have to vary your behavior) once you test how it behaves.

```
if (typeof body === "string") {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
}
```

Comment: Rockstar answer, thanks! I have a node.js site. I'm using a body parser middleware, but when my server makes requests to the mailchimp api, I just use the request library, which I don't believe automatically parses. I have to dig in and see what the response headers are if 'application/json' is there, and hopefully soon, they'll be node.js wrapper for the api. Until then, I'm using a typeof conditional. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the API, usually you get the response header `Content-type: application/json`. If that is the case there's probably no need to parse the response as most of the clients will understand that it's a json object and parse it for you. Anyhow, not all clients will do this automatically.

Comment: Not aware with that, but at least jquery does work like that, if the content type is not application/json, you get a plain string (at least in my experience)

Comment: *"as the client will understand that it's a json object."* That depends entirely on what client you are using, whether it be `http` module directly or something like `npm install request`. the `http` module doesn't do this parsing for you.

Comment: thats why i said "theres probably" but i will edit my answer to clarify it.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks! For now, since the api is changing, I'll write a conditional, just to protect against changes : )